# Network Analyst in Arcgis to generate the network for further analysis what should the attribute table must contain?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I was trying to use the function Network Analyst in Arcgis to generate the network to display the small world phenomenon, so i have to transport the shape file for winbugs to use it for further geostatical analysis, so I was wondering that what should the attribute table must contain in the shapefile to let me make an adjacency matric for further calculate.(my shapefile type is polyline or point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Point layer must have Sequence field (a field that indicates the order of the stops) and Name of the stop is helpful. If you want to use Weights, your lines layer must have a field for that weights (length in meters, or allowed speed for example).